# Python - Downloading from google drive with progress bar

Tags: python, download

I am trying to create a system where a file will be downloaded from python, 
however I would like to have a progress bar to show progress.

I am currently using [googledrivedownloader](https://github.com/ndrplz/google-drive-downloader) and this:

```
from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader as gdd
gdd.download_file_from_google_drive(file_id='*id*', 
dest_path='.\bah.zip', unzip=False)`
```

Which works but has no progress bar

The documentation suggests setting `showsize=True` to show progress, but I have been unable to do this successfully.

Update: I have tried to create and object with first `from google_drive_downloader import GoogleDriveDownloader`
then
`gdd = GoogleDriveDownloader(showsize=True)`

but I am getting an error that: "GoogleDriveDownloader() takes no arguments"

Update 2: I am using the Pip version, and as suggested it is possible that the code has not been released for pip. Thank you @geckos! I will try using the master branch asap!

Comment: You need to create an object first. You should `import GoogleDriveDownloader` and then let `gdd = GoogleDriveDownloader(showsize=True)`.

Comment: @JackMoody Source code shows that `google_drive_downloader` 's author had decorate every method as `@staticmethod` and more importantly there is no `__init__()` in the `GoogleDriveDownloader` class, thus there is no need to create an object. I think things will be work if simply add `showsize=True` after `... unzip=False`

Comment: Are you using the master branch? There is an issue talking about this. I don't know if the progress bar code is released with the pip version